# help me understand python

Tags: python

Initialize an array of arrays:

```
M = [[]]*(24*60/5)
```

Append the number 2 to the 51st array in `M`

```
M[50].append(2)
```

What is in M?

```
...
[2]
[2]
[2]
[2]
[2]
[2]
[2]
[2]
...
```

Every element in M is the array `[2]`

What am I missing? I suspect that every `[]` that I initially initialize is a reference to the same space in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **did** create an array of arrays.  But you then assigned the same `[]` to every one of its entries.

It's not that every time you call `[]` it gives you the same array - it's that you only called `[]` once.

Get it?

Comment: Thanks. So how do I force python to give me a unique array within each cell of the parent array?

Comment: `M = [[] for _ in range(24*60/5)]` is the simplest way (it's a list comprehension).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you got it, as Borealid pointed out.

If you want many times a different list, you can do:

```
M = [[] for _ in range(24*60/5)]
```

The `_` is just a regular variable name (variables can start with an underscore), but it tells readers of the code "I'm an unimportant variable, with no special meaning associated to it".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/.

The construct you liked to use is really hard to read and "Readability counts".

Comment: I got that solution from StackOverflow.

Comment: It's just easier to learn this rules to write good, pythonic code when you're a beginner ...